# Form errors not being rendered on sign up page in devise (rails 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using devise to manage authentication in my rails 7 app, and everything works fine, except that when I submit the sign up form with no information in it, the form errors don't get rendered and I get this error in the console:

```
Error: Form responses must redirect to another location
    at B.requestSucceededWithResponse (turbo.es2017-esm.js:786:27)
    at H.receive (turbo.es2017-esm.js:549:27)
    at H.perform (turbo.es2017-esm.js:524:31)
```

In the log in page form errors get rendered, but not in the sign up page

I already tried adding this line: `config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to properly integrate Devise with Rails 7 with Turbo, you should configure some extra stuff:

- You can disable Turbo in devise forms, via `data: { turbo: "false" }`. You can see an example here: https://github.com/ralixjs/rails-ralix-tailwind/blob/main/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
- Or alternatively: you can add a custom `failure_app` for Devise, see an example in the following screencast: https://gorails.com/episodes/devise-hotwire-turbo
- Or alternatively: official support for Turbo was added to Devise (https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/5548), but still not released to RubyGems (you can try it by pointing to `main` branch in your Gemfile)